# CI Router check the domain from database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

Im new to CI  need help in routing the url to sub domain based on the database value

by using wildcard rule i have set the sub domain on server, now i have to check sub domain exists in database,if the name exists in db then i have redirect to main controller else i have redirect main site (default controller)

currently im checking sub domain in main controller index method

```
   $server = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $domain = $server[0]; 
   $this->usercontroller->checkdomain($domain);
```

need help i doing its better way using router(bootstrap method)

Comment: You can create your own `router` and intercept the request before it reaches the controller (search MY_router in the CI forums) or, what I have started doing is using the `404_override` route to get the requested URL, check it and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question however this works for me.   This may point someone in the right direction. Feel free to ask me specifics on the code as well.

```
//$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

$route['404_override'] = '';
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])

{

```
case 'losey.co':

case 'www.losey.co':

    $route['default_controller'] = "dashboard";

break;  

default:
    //This query's the sites table and checks the domain / subdomain and then shows the correct default_controller
    $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
        $db =& DB();
        $db->where('nameshort',  array_shift(explode(".",$server)));
        $db->or_where('domain', $server);
        $query = $db->get( 'sites' );
        //$query = $db->get_where('sites', array('nameshort' => 'test'), 1);

        $result = $query->result();
        foreach( $result as $row )
        {
            $route['default_controller'] = $row->home;
        }
break;
```